# PSQL custom type insertion results NULL

Tags: insert, psql, composite-types

I have a table and a composite type:

```
CREATE TYPE server AS (
    id      text,
    load    int
)
CREATE TABLE live_log (
    id              serial      PRIMARY KEY,
    edges           server[],
    origins         server[],
    time            time        NOT NULL,
    date            date        NOT NULL,
    day             text
)
```

I'm trying to insert a row in live_log table:

```
INSERT INTO live_log(edges, origins, day, date, time)
VALUES (
    ARRAY[ROW('edge1', 20),ROW('edge2', 30)]::server[],
    ARRAY[ROW('origin1', 20),ROW('origin2', 30)]::server[],
    'Monday',
    '11-01-1994',
    '11:00:30'
);
```

But the result of insertion of composite type arrays remains null, regardless to any changes at INSERT query. 
[image: my db results]

Can anyone help me to figure out whats wrong with my INSERT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a select query to cast the arrays to text and DBeaver will give you a representation of the server array:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    edges::text,
    origins::text,
    time,
    date,
    day
FROM live_log
```

[image: DBeaver Output Window]

DBeaver doesn't know how to represent the "server" type. From what I can tell, DBeaver checks against the standard Postgres types and if the type doesn't match one of those, it bails and throws the following:

> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCException: Can't resolve struct type 'server'

While you can't directly open the table object and view the "Data" tab using this method, you could create a view based on the table for easier inspection.

Also, serge-rider is usually responsive to feature requests submitted via [GitHub](https://github.com/serge-rider/dbeaver/issues). Don't want to speak on his behalf, but this might be a case for an enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

It's ambaresing. DBeaver for some reason refuses to display composite type array. Console psql interface showed more full output.

[image: console output]